# Replicate logmein.com behavior for smart devices

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, remote-access

I have several smart devices that run Windows CE5 with our application written in .NETCF 3.5. The smart devices are connected to the internet with integrated GPRS modems. My clients would like a remote support option but VNC and similar tools doesn't seem to be able to do the job. I found several issues with VNC to get it to work. First it has severe performance issues when ran on the smart device. The second issue is that the internet provider has a firewall that blocks all incoming requests if they didn't originate from the smart device itself. Therefore I cannot initiate a remote desktop session with the smart devices since the request didn't originate from the smart device.

We could get our own APN however they are too expensive and the monthly cost is too great for the amount of smart devices we have deployed. It's more economical for us if we could add development costs to the initial product cost because our customers dislike high monthly costs and rather pay a large sum up front instead. A remote support solution would also allow us to minimize our onsite support.

That's why we more or less decided to roll our own remote desktop solution. We have code for capturing images on the smart device and only get the data that has changed since the last cycle. What we need is to make a communication solution like logmein.com (doesn't support WinCE5) where the smart devices connect to a server from which we then can stream the data to our support personnel's clients. Basically the smart device initiates a connection to our server and start delivering screen data when the server requests it. A support client connects to the server and gets a list of available streams and then select one to listen in on.

Any suggestions for how to do it considering we have to do the solution in .NETCF 3.5 on the smart devices? We have limited communication experience beyond simple soap web-services.

Comment: We have implemented our own VNC server for Windows CE 5.0, which is open source if you want to use it. It also supports 16-bit color, which improves the performance over the internet. The server is written in C/C++, but we launch it as a separate process from within C#. If you are interested I can provide the link. One advantage to VNC is that you can use any existing VNC client, on smart phones etc, to connect

Comment: Thank you for your offer but can you let the server initiate the connection to the client and not the normal way where the client connects to the server? The major issue is that the GPRS provider's firewall drops all connection request that doesn't originate from the smart device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking for a suggestion, I'll suggest this:

Don't reinvent.  Reuse whatever you can.  You can perform tunneling with SSH, so make an SSH connection (say, a port of PuTTY or plink, inside a loop) out via GPRS on your smart device; forward remote ports to local ports, bound to the SSH server's local address (127.0.0.1 (sshd):4567 => localhost (smart_device_01):4567).  Your clients connect to your SSH server and access the assigned port for each device.

With that said, that's probably not the answer you're looking for.  Below - the answer you're probably looking for.

---

Based on my analysis of how LogMeIn works, you'll want to make an HTTPS or TLS server where your smart devices will push data.  Let's call it your tunnel server.

You'll probably want to spawn a new thread that repeatedly attempts to make connections to the tunnel server (**outbound connections** from smart device to the server, per your specified requirement).  With a protocol like BEEP/BXXP, you can encapsulate and multiplex message-oriented or stream-oriented sessions.  Wrap BXXP/BEEP into TLS, and tunnel through to your tunnel server.  BEEP lets you multiplex streams onto one connection -- if you want the full capabilities of an in-house LogMeIn solution, you'll want to use something like this.

Once a connection is established, make a new BEEP session.  With the new session, tell the tunnel server your system identification information (device name, device authentication signature).  Write heartbeat data (timestamp periodically) into this new session.

Set up a callback (or another thread) which interfaces to your BEEP control session.  Watch for a message requesting service.  When such a request comes in, spawn the required threads to copy data from your custom remote-display protocol and push this data back through the same channel.

This sets the basic premise for your Smart Device's program.  You can add functionality to this as you desire, say, to match what LMI's IT Reach subscription provides (remote registry, secure tunneled Telnet, remote filesystem, remote printing, remote sound... you get the idea)

I'll make some assumptions that you know how to properly secure all this stuff for authentication and authorization for your clients (Is user foo allowed to access smart device bar?).

On your tunnel server, start a server socket (listening for **inbound connections**, or from the perspective of smart devices, smart device **outbound connections**) that demultiplexes connections and sessions.  Once a connection is opened, fire up BEEP and register a callback / start a thread to wait for the authentication/heartbeat session.  Perform the required checks for AAA to smart devices -- are these devices allowed, are they known, how much does it cost, etc.  **Your tunnel server forwards data on behalf of your smart devices.**  For each BEEP session, attach a name (device name) to the BEEP session after the AAA procedures succeed; on failure, close the connection and let the AAA mechanism know (to block attackers).  Your tunnel server should also set up what's required for interacting with the frontend -- that is, it should have the code to interact with BEEP to demultiplex the stream for your remote display data.

On your frontend server (can be the same box as the tunnel server), install the routine for AAA -- check if the user is known, if the user is allowed, how much the user should be charged, etc.  Once all the checks are passed, make a secured connection from the frontend server to tunnel server.  Get the device names that the tunnel server knows that the user is allowed to access.  At this point, you should be able to get a "plaintext" stream, based on the device name, from the tunnel server.  Forward this stream back to the user (via TLS, for example, or again via BEEP over TLS), or send the required configuration for your remote display client to connect to your tunnel server with the required parameters to access the remote display protocol's stream.

Comment: Just tooting my own horn here. :)  The official version of PocketPuTTY, while unmaintained, works well on the Windows Mobile platform, and will likely work well on Windows CE platforms.  It includes some port forwarding capabilities.  I keep a fork of PocketPuTTY that has a few additional patches, some created/collected by Ken Johnson/Skywing/nyaneve.net.  If you make changes to PocketPuTTY, I'd love to hear about them.

Comment: The answer I was looking for just convinced my boss to put that feature on hold ;) The putty solution certainly looks promising though. We are however most likely changing platform in the near future and we will use linux instead so the remote problem probably got a lot easier. Thanks for your answer.